# how can i make number of objects of a particular model under one specific model in django 3.0

Tags: python-3.x, django, many-to-many, mixed-models, django-3.0

i want to attach a model called 'task' which comes with two attributes

```
class Task(models.Model):
task_name = models.CharField(default='Task Name' ,max_length = 100,)
task_description = models.CharField(default='Task Description' ,max_length = 100,)
```

to another model called branch

```
class branch(models.Model):

branch_name  = models.CharField(default='Branch_Name' ,max_length = 100,)
subject_1= models.CharField(max_length = 100,)
subject_2= models.CharField(max_length = 100,)
subject_3= models.CharField(max_length = 100,)
```

in this , the working is simple in each branch there are number of subjects to study , under each subject
there can be number of tasks.

how can i build one efficient app which link the model 'task' to model 'branch'. so that i can create number of branches and in each branch there can be number of tasks under each subject,each task is differentiated from one another using field reference ' task_name' which comes under the model 'task' .

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

```
class Task(models.Model):
    task_name = models.CharField(default='Task Name' ,max_length = 100)
    task_description = models.CharField(default='Task Description' ,max_length = 100)

class Branch(models.Model):
    branch_name = models.CharField(default='Branch_Name' ,max_length = 100)
    subject_1 = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    subject_2 = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    subject_3 = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    tasks = models.ManyToManyField(Task)
```